# Como utilizar un metodo "compareTo" para hallar la pelicula mas antigua?

Tags: java, poo, clase, método, interface

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio sobre las ventas de un video club, el video club cuenta con 3 productos: peliculas, series y videojuegos. Cada producto tiene su clase y en el metodo main declaro 4 objetos de tipo pelicula, 4 de series y asi. Cada clase tiene sobreescrito el metodo toString, y lo uso para mostrar todos los datos del objeto (en el caso de una pelicula, titulo, año, genero, director, etc.), cada clase a su vez cuenta con un metodo compareTo que compara la antiguedad en caso de ser pelicula, la cantidad de temporadas si es serie, y la duracion total si es un videojuego, en el ejercicio no especifica si este metodo devuelve algo o no, que se le pasa por parametro ni nada.

Les dejo la clase Pelicula

```
package video_club;

public class Pelicula implements Entregable{



    private String titulo;
    private Integer año ;
    private boolean prestado = false;
    private String genero = "no definido";
    private String director;

    Pelicula(){

    }

    Pelicula(String titulo, String director){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.director = director;
        año = 9999;

    }

    Pelicula(String titulo, Integer año, String genero, String director){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.año = año;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.director = director;
    }



    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public Integer getAño() {
        return año;
    }

    public void setAño(Integer año) {
        this.año = año;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public void entregar() {
        prestado = true;
    }

    public void devolver() {
        prestado = false;
    }

    public boolean isPrestado() {
        return prestado;
    }

    public String compareTo(Object a) {
        String pelicula = "";
        if(año < ((Pelicula)a).getAño()) pelicula = toString();
        else pelicula = ((Pelicula) a).toString();
        return pelicula;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String info = "";
        info = "Titulo: " + titulo + ", Año: " + año + ", Genero: " + genero + ", Director: " + director;
        return info;

    }


}
```

"Método compareTo (Object a), compara las horas estimadas en los
videojuegos y en las series el numero de temporadas. y en las Películas el
año" Esto es lo que dice el ejercicio.

Mi gran duda es como hago la siguiente parte del ejercicio:

"Por último, indica que Videojuego tiene más horas estimadas, la serie con
mas temporadas y la Película mas antigua. Muéstralos en pantalla con toda
su información (usa el método toString())."

Mi duda es como puedo hacer el metodo compareTo y como utilizarlo para encontrar la pelicula mas antigua, la serie con mas temporadas etc. intente hacerlo con el compareTo y un For en el metodo main pero no me funciono, les paso el codigo del main.

```
package video_club;

public class App {

    private Integer a = 0;
    private Integer b = 0;
    private Integer c = 0;

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Integer c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void ProductosEntregados(Pelicula a, Serie b, Videojuego c){

        if(a.isPrestado() == true) this.a++;
        if(b.isPrestado() == true) this.b++;
        if(c.isPrestado() == true) this.c++;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer i;
        String serie = "";
        String pelicula = "";
        String videojuego = "";


        App a = new App();
        Pelicula [] peliculas = new Pelicula[4];
        Serie [] series = new Serie[4];
        Videojuego [] videojuegos = new Videojuego[4]; 


        peliculas[0] = new Pelicula("El Exorcista",1200,"Terror","K.Ramone");
        peliculas[1] = new Pelicula("El Conjuro", "J.Rawson");
        peliculas[2] = new Pelicula("La Vida Es Bella", 40, "Drama", "B.Smith");
        peliculas[3] = new Pelicula("Rapido y Furioso",50,"Accion","S.Rhoodes");


        series [0] = new Serie();
        series [1] = new Serie("Breaking Bad",21,"Suspenso", "J.Jhonson");
        series [2] = new Serie("The Walking Dead", 17, "Accion/Aventura", "M.Kennedy");
        series [3] = new Serie("Lost",15,"Suspenso","H.Ted");


        videojuegos [0] = new Videojuego();
        videojuegos [1] = new Videojuego("NFSHP", 700);
        videojuegos [2] = new Videojuego("League of Legends",600,"MOBA","Riot Games");
        videojuegos [3] = new Videojuego("Lineage II",20,"MMORPG","Eidos");


        peliculas[2].entregar();
        peliculas[0].entregar();
        peliculas[1].entregar();
        series[1].entregar();
        series[2].entregar();
        videojuegos[0].entregar();
        videojuegos[2].entregar();
        videojuegos[3].entregar();
        videojuegos[0].devolver();


        for(i=0;i<peliculas.length;i++) a.ProductosEntregados(peliculas[i], series[i], videojuegos[i]);


        System.out.println("Peliculas entregadas: " + a.getA() + "// Series entregadas: " + a.getB() + "// Videojuegos entregados: " + a.getC() + "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------");

    }

}
```

Comment: Creo que la idea es que tu clase debe implementar `java.util.Comparable`. Y luego usar las funcionalidades de `java.util` para ordenar la lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes utiliza un TreeSet como contenedor de Peliculas, ya que con el mismo solo sobreescribiendo el método compareTo te los ordena automáticamente por año(si así lo especificas) de forma ascendente.

En tu clase Pelicula sobreescribe el metodo compareTo:

Lo que hace este método es devolver un número negativo si el this.getAño() < p.getAño(); cero en el caso de que sean los mismos datos o un valor positivo si this.getAño() > p.getAño()

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Pelicula p = (Pelicula) o;
    return this.getAño() - p.getAño();
}
```

Luego en tu clase App, creas las cuatro instancias y despues las agregas a la lista.
Los elementos se iran ordenanado a medida que los ingresas. Esto es una desventaja para cuando se ingresa una gran cantidad de datos, ya que se vuelve muy lento para ingresar y ordenar los datos.

```
Set<Pelicula> peliculas = new TreeSet<>();
peliculas.add(new Pelicula("El Exorcista", 1200, "Terror", "K.Ramone"));
peliculas.add(new Pelicula("El Conjuro", "J.Rawson"));
peliculas.add(new Pelicula("La Vida Es Bella", 40, "Drama", "B.Smith"));
peliculas.add(new Pelicula("Rapido y Furioso", 50, "Accion", "S.Rhoodes"));
System.out.println(peliculas);
```

La salida es:

```
[Titulo: La Vida Es Bella, Año: 40, Genero: Drama, Director: B.Smith
, Titulo: Rapido y Furioso, Año: 50, Genero: Accion, Director: S.Rhoodes
, Titulo: El Exorcista, Año: 1200, Genero: Terror, Director: K.Ramone
, Titulo: El Conjuro, Año: 9999, Genero: no definido, Director: J.Rawson
]
```

Despues ya seguro sabras obtener el elemento que deseas.